# number of integer solutions of a weighted inequality

Tags: combinatorics

Find the number of integer solutions to the inequality $x_1+\cdots+x_m+ry\leq d$ such that:

- $r\in\mathbb{N}$ is a constant
- $\forall i\in[m]:x_i\geq0$
- $y\geq 0$

Maybe just an approximation: I thought of $\frac{d^{m+1}}{(m+1)!r}$.

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with generating functions? The idea is that we use a formal power series to encode the number of solutions. We will work with ordinary generating functions (OGFs) here, manipulating the formal geometric series.

So for each $i \in [m]$, we can assign $0, 1, 2, \ldots$ to $x_{i}$. So the OGF for $x_{i}$ is $f_{i}(x) = x^{0} + x^{1} + x^{2} + \ldots = \dfrac{1}{1-x}$.

Now for $y \in \mathbb{N}$, $ry$ contributes $ry$ to the sum. So the OGF for $y$ is $f_{y}(x) = x^{0r} + x^{1r} + x^{2r} + \ldots = \dfrac{1}{1-x^{r}}$. So the OGF for the inequality above is:

$$f(x) = \left( \dfrac{1}{1-x} \right)^{m} \left( \dfrac{1}{1-x^{r}} \right)$$

Now expand out $f(x)$ and add up the coefficients for $x^{0}, x^{1}, \ldots, x^{d}$.

Comment: A simplification is possible by noting that the number of solutions to $x_1+\dots+x_m + ry \le d$ is the same as the number of solutions to $x_1+\dots+x_m + ry +x_{m+1} = d$ .